# Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql

Criando a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE Corrida(
       Id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
       BairroDaPartida CHAR(30),
       Valor NUMBER(5),
       Kms NUMBER(5),
       Prefixo CHAR(4),
       CPF NUMBER(8) FOREIGN KEY,
       CONSTRAINT FkCorridaPassageiro FOREIGN KEY (CPF) REFERENCES Passageiro,
);
```

Comment: Remova a vírgula depois da última linha do comando. Depois de Passageiro.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Corrida(
       Id NUMBER(6) PRIMARY KEY,
       BairroDaPartida CHAR(30),
       Valor NUMBER(5),
       Kms NUMBER(5),
       Prefixo CHAR(4),
       CPF NUMBER(8) FOREIGN KEY,
       CONSTRAINT FkCorridaPassageiro FOREIGN KEY (CPF) REFERENCES Passageiro
);